# Specify specific source apt repository for package

Tags: debian, apt, package-management

On Debian `sid`, to install a web service, I ran a script which added NodeJS repo and installed `nodejs` package. The problem is `apt` resolved it to Debian's package version `8.11.2~dfsg-1`, which does not include `npm` for some reason, instead of NodeJS repo's version `8.11.2-1nodesource1`. The lack of `npm` messed with the script that expected it to be present after installation of `nodejs`.

I solved it by manually doing `apt install nodejs=8.11.2-1nodesource1`, but that's a temporary workaround. Is there a way I can specify on my script to prefer particular repository regardless of version?

**EDIT**

```
# apt policy nodejs
nodejs:
  Installed: 8.11.2-1nodesource1
  Candidate: 8.11.2-1nodesource1
  Version table:
 *** 8.11.2-1nodesource1 500
        500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_8.x sid/main arm64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     8.11.2~dfsg-1 990
        990 http://deb.debian.org/debian unstable/main arm64 Packages
```

Comment: What does `apt policy nodejs` output?

Comment: @StephenKitt, edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way I can specify on my script to prefer particular repository regardless of version?

You should pin the external source using the `origin` option to assign a high priority to "the external source" instead of using the `release` name.

e,g: Add the following lines to your `/etc/apt/preferences.d/preferences`:

```
Package: *
Pin: origin deb.nodesource.com
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

The `apt-cache policy nodejs` will be:

```
Candidate: 8.11.2-1nodesource1

Version table:
     8.11.2-1nodesource1 1001
       1001 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_8.x sid/main amd64 Packages
     8.11.2~dfsg-1 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian sid/main amd64 Packages
```

The package `nodejs` will be installed from `nodsource.com` through `apt install nodejs`

Generally if you add the nodejs source (using the setup script) the package `nodejs` will be installed from `nodesource.com` without adding the complete package name to `apt` or using pinning way. (it can be an issue and you can [report it here](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues)).

If the package available from multiples repository (debian repo and external repo) you can use the debian release tag to install the package from **debian repository**. let's say the `nodejs` is pinned to `1001` and you need to install the package from debian Sid:

```
apt install nodejs/unstable
```

[AptPreferenecs](https://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences)

**Edit**

The package `nodejs` is pinned to 990 , it will be installed from debian repository. remove the nodejs from your `preferences` file then run:

```
apt update
apt install nodejs
```

The package nodejs should be installed from nodesource repository.

Comment: The script added the repo and it still preferred `dfsg` package. I edited question with `apt policy`.

Comment: @Oxwivi remove the pinned package then you will be able to install the package from nodesource.

Comment: I did not pin anything, this is the `policy` Stephen asked for before acting upon the suggestion in your answer.

Comment: `/etc/apt/preferences.d/preferences` is empty as well.

Comment: @Oxwivi changing the pin priority to 1001 of the package nodejs following the answer may instruct apt to install the package from nodesouce.

Comment: Probably. I was just informing you that I didn't mess with anything before or after I posted the question.